# What is the 'link' attribute used for in a <div> element?

Tags: html

I encountered something at work which looks like it may populate a list of links from a data source, but I'm not sure. Here's the code:

```
<div mc-support-link-collection header-title="Related Documents" links="support.links">
```

According to w3schools, (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_link.asp), the link attribute-at least when used in the `<body>` tag-sets link colors on a page. Would this have the same meaning in a `<div>` tag or a different meaning?
Thanks!

Comment: The `links` attribute is probably being referenced from Javascript code and has no effect otherwise.  You will have to examine the entire context to determine its effect.  It is not standard HTML.

Comment: #ThatsProbablyAValidAnswer

Comment: `links` != `link`. That, and it looks like someone just made up their own attribute rather than using a custom `data-*` attribute.